# 7 Byte Hex to Dec Conversion

Tags: vba, excel, hex

I need to convert 7 byte hexadecimal values in an Excel column to the decimal equivalents in an adjacent column.

I have over 2000 unique values to convert from hexadecimal to decimal.

I got as far as using Excel's hex2bin and then bin2dec formulas.
I found that Excel is rounding up the least significant 4 decimal places.

Example:
7Byte Hex: `0x803277323A8904`
Excel Output: `36084284544158000`
Correct Decimal Number: `36084284544157956`

Comment: Do you have a deciphering key? Like for each value in 7Byte Hex you have a corresponding value in Decimal Number? If so let me know, i can help you make a deciphering code via `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Hi @DirtyDeffy, no deciphering key... just straight hex to dec conversions... although it seems from other responses that excel may be the limiting factor with my issue...

Comment: Am I missing something? Your least significant digit in hex is 4 - surely your decimal should also therefore end in 4?

Answer (score 2):

This is a small variation of [Rick Rothstein's code](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/578667-use-dec2bin-function-vba-edit-macro.html)

```
Function HexToDecs(ByVal HexString As String) As String
  Dim X As Integer
  Dim BinStr As String
  Const BinValues = "0000000100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111"
  If Left$(HexString, 2) Like "&[hH]" Then
    HexString = Mid$(HexString, 3)
  End If
  If Len(HexString) <= 23 Then
    For X = 1 To Len(HexString)
      BinStr = BinStr & Mid$(BinValues, 4 * Val("&h" & Mid$(HexString, X, 1)) + 1, 4)
    Next
    HexToDecd = CDec(0)
    For X = 0 To Len(BinStr) - 1
      HexToDecd = HexToDecd + Val(Mid(BinStr, Len(BinStr) - X, 1)) * 2 ^ X
    Next
  Else
    ' Number is too big, handle error here
  End If
  HexToDecs = CStr(HexToDecd)
End Function
```

[image]

NOTE:

- This *UDF()* returns a String representation of the integer to avoid the 15 digit limitation to true numeric values.
- I have elected not to start my input string with **0x**

Answer (score 0):

> Excel maximum number of digits. In Excel spreadsheet, there is a limit for storing a number in a Cell, which is 15 digits (15 numbers) regardless of whether the numbers are decimal places. Excel call this “15 significant digits of precision” which adheres to “IEEE 754”.Feb 24, 2015

In order to have `36084284544157956`, which has 17 digits, save the cell as a Text.

---

Even VBA does not like displaying such big numbers:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String: inputString = "123456789012345678"
    Dim someValue As Double

    someValue = inputString
    Debug.Print someValue + 1

End Sub
```

gets: `1,23456789012346E+17`

---

To present the text value in Excel cell, make sure that you format the cell before putting the text in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    With Range("D2")
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value2 = "123456789012345678"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Vityata. Is it possible to present the VBA output in a cell formatted for text or would this prevent the VB module from running?

Comment: I don't quite understand where to configure the range of data that i would like converted from hex to dec with your script. Are you able to explain this to me please?

Comment: @Aston - here - `Range("D2").NumberFormat = "@"`